# IBM MobileFirst Operational Analytics no show data

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, mobilefirst-analytics

It's in a pre-production installation, with Windows Server 2008 and WAS Liberty.
In the Liberty is deployed IBM MobileFirst Platform 7.0, Analytics, a MobileFirst runtime, an application and an adapter.
In the Operational Analytics there are not data/applications/servers/...
[image: There are not data/applications]

The server.xml file contains:

```
<application location="analytics.ear" name="analytics-ear" type="ear">
      <application-bnd>
        ...
       </application-bnd>
    </application>

<jndiEntry jndiName="wl.analytics.url" value='http://maquinalocal.dominio.local:9080/analytics-service/data'/>
    <jndiEntry jndiName="wl.analytics.console.url" value='http://maquinalocal.dominio.local:9080/analytics/console'/>
    <jndiEntry jndiName="wl.analytics.queues" value='"1"'/>
    <jndiEntry jndiName="wl.analytics.queue.size" value='"0"'/>
    <jndiEntry jndiName="wl.analytics.logs.forward" value='true'/>
```

The messages.log is:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BxAEyIioPI2YSTByRFF2eWdkQ2c/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Have you tried by setting the wl.analytics.queue.size = 1 ?

Comment: Did it work before? Is this really a live production environment or a pre-production environment?

Comment: Are your MobileFirst Console Server and MobileFirst Analytics Server being hosted on the same physical server?

Comment: it's a preproductión enviroment

Answer (score 1):

I had faced a similar issue on a WASND production server environtment, but that was for the client side logs not being displayed in the analytics console. In a production server environment for the client logs to be seen in the analytics console along with setting up analytics console I had to also create a log profile in MobileFirst operations console.

- In the MobileFirst console open the Client Log Profiles tab.
- Click on the Add Profile tab here
- Select different filters from the list that comes up and finish the profile creation.

Restarted the server once the log profile is created. After this I was able to view the client side logs in the analytics console when they were generated.

Comment: I tried this but the analytics console is empty yet

Comment: Make sure your wl.analytics.url and wl.analytics.console.url are correct. http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSHS8R_7.0.0/com.ibm.worklight.installconfig.doc/monitor/t_configuring_op_analytics.html . In my setup the context root was different, so accordingly I had used that in the url's . Other properties I had set were wl.analytics.logs.forward=true
wl.analytics.username=admin
wl.analytics.password=admin
wl.analytics.queues=1
wl.analytics.queue.size=1
wl.analytics.forwardIntervalInSeconds=5

Answer (score 0):

I also had the same issue. Following configuration worked for me.

```
    <application location="analytics.ear" name="analytics-ear"  type="ear" context-root="analytics">
      <application-bnd>
        <security-role name="worklightadmin">
           <user name="username"/>
        </security-role>
        <security-role name="worklightdeployer">
        </security-role>
        <security-role name="worklightmonitor">
        </security-role>
        <security-role name="worklightoperator">
        </security-role>
       </application-bnd>
        <classloader delegation="parentLast">
        </classloader>
    </application>

    <jndiEntry jndiName="wl.analytics.url" value="http://<domain>:<port>/analytics-service/data"/>
    <jndiEntry jndiName="wl.analytics.console.url" value='http://<domain>:<port>/analytics/console'/>
    <jndiEntry jndiName="wl.analytics.queues" value="1"/>
    <jndiEntry jndiName="wl.analytics.queue.size" value="1"/>
    <jndiEntry jndiName="wl.analytics.logs.forward" value="true"/>
    <jndiEntry jndiName="wl.analytics.username" value="username"/>
    <jndiEntry jndiName="wl.analytics.password" value="password"/>
```

Also, I noticed that you have provided values like **value='"1"'** instead of **value="1"** which could be the issue(not sure about it though).